# The usage of " is of "

Tags: grammar

Here are some examples:

The far side of the Moon **is of** particular interest to the scientists.

Anglo **is of** European origin

Morning exercises **is of** benefit to your health

So what does "is of" in these sentences mean?

Comment: Where did you see the second and third examples, and are they both supposed to be full sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Like many posters on this site, you are linking the wrong words together.

'The far side of the Moon is *of particular interest.'* (= particularly interesting)

'[Something] is *of European origin*' (= originated in Europe. *Anglo* is a prefix meaning *English* or *British*, so your sentence doesn't make sense.)

'Morning exercises are *of benefit to your health*. (= good for you)